# BIg-$O$ notation true/false

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I am working on question about big-$O$ notation, I think I understand the idea of big-$O$ but the following notation make me confuse

$$ n! = 2^{O(n\log n)}$$

$$ n^{\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}} = O(1)$$

$$ n^{\log^4 n} = 2^{\log^{O(1)}n} $$

My though referencing [Show that $3^n = 2^{O(n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719451/show-that-3n-2on?noredirect=1&lq=1)

for the first one id take log base $2$ on both side

$$\lg(n!) = O(n\log n)\lg(2)$$

I know that $lg(n!)$ is $O(n\log n)$

$$\lg(n!) = O(n\log n)$$

Does it mean the answer is true?
but How can I deal with the others

Comment: For the first is essential, that $2^n$ is increasing.

Comment: @zkutch Do you mean that we are considering when n is a large number? But how does it help to think of this kind of notation

Comment: From your question I understand, that we are considering $\infty$ as limit point for non negative sequences, so, yes, $n$ is "large" number. How to work formally I wrote in my answer for 3-d example.

Answer (score 1):

For $3^\text{rd}$, for simplicity, let's take base $2$ for $\log$ in power and knowing $f(n)=5 \in O(1)$ we have:
$$n^{\log_2^4 n}=2^{(\log_2 n)\cdot (\log_2^4 n)} = 2^{\log^5_2 n}  \in 2^{\log^{O(1)}n}$$
$2^\text{nd}$ seems not correct as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}} = \infty$.